# gh cli create release from tagged draft template

Tags: github, github-cli

Let say I have release draft template tagged 1.10

Now I would like to publish a new 1.10 release from this draft with gh cli but I [see](https://cli.github.com/manual/gh_release_create) no options for that or do not understanding how can I achieve it

If I run `gh release create 1.10 --generate-notes` it will create new release notes which is undesirable (my draft uses another template). If I add `-d` flag, it will create new draft. All I want is to publish from existing tagged draft something like (dummy command) `gh release create 1.10 --from-draft` - is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the edit option to publish the release.

Publish a release that was previously a draft

```
$ gh release edit v1.0 --draft=false
```